# Drop down into the screen animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, splash-screen

There is a new requirement for me. I have added animations for switching between the activities. There are two buttons in a activity, namely forward and backward button. When I press the forward button, the existing activity has to move into the screen and new activity has to slide in from the right. Similarly when I press the reverse button, the existing activity is pushed to left by the new activity which rises to center of the screen. I have coded successfully for sliding right and sliding left by creating an animation XML file. But how to code for moving into the screen and rising from the screen animation?

Comment: The code for sliding in right 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="700" android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%" />
    
</set>

Comment: [Check](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the Translation with `android:fromYDelta` as 100% and `android:toYDelta` to 0 this will animate your activity from bottom to top and if you want the reverse direction you can reverse the `android:fromYDelta` to 0% and `android:toYDelta` to 100%

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
```

I hope this will fit to your requirement.

Comment: No it is not working. I want a effect like the present activity is pushed left by the new one which is raising up the screen.